# Lock in DB2 with Spring JPA until INSERT

Tags: java, spring, jpa, db2, locking

In DB2 (IBM) I have several tables with historicized entries, only the most current row (highest timestamp) with a certain key holds the data that is actually used in other applications. So when a change to the values with a certain key is made, the old rows stay and new rows are added with a new timestamp.

Changing the values (=adding new rows) is supposed to happen via a web application, using Spring. But when a user sees the values for a certain key and decides to change the values, it should not be possible for other users to change the values while he is typing in the new values.

I am not very experienced with locking and even less with Spring JPA. Is it possible to lock the tables so that no one can insert sth. with the same key (or if not, lock the whole table) until the user submits his change or cancels?

Comment: `(or if not, lock the whole table)` - This is a terrible idea, BTW, especially if you're going to have multiple people editing multiple different entries.  Note, too, that actually locking has bad results when somebody does something like go on vacation.  Do you actually need to lock, though, or just reject changes when the changestamp of the entity being updated doesn't match the most recent row?  I'm half tempted to say "make this a DB trigger", since you could have it swap out an `UPDATE` for an `INSERT`.

Comment: So locks are not automatically released when the connection ist lost? Another solution I thought of would be to only insert if there is no higher timestamp than the one I read, Something like what is explained here in the SQL part: https://www.pmg.com/blog/how-to-insert-only-if-a-condition-is-met-in-sql-and-php/

Comment: `So locks are not automatically released when the connection ist lost?`  Might depend, but you're assuming the connection is going to be lost in the first place.  The "traditional" problem here is people not even realizing they have a record locked, then calling in sick the next day.  The problem with the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` idea is that the query isn't necessarily atomic (two separate users might run the `SELECT` portion at the same time, get the same answer, and attempt to insert) - I can't recall, and I'm not seeing anything in the documentation.

Comment: At minimum, you should at least look at "Optimistic locking", which will prevent the application from _updating_ records if someone else has already done so.  Getting it to insert records safely instead of update is harder - you might find it easier to use separate history tables that are populated via triggers or some other method (it also means you don't have to do `FETCH FIRST`-type queries to read your rows).

Comment: No, I lied, I think - the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`_should_ be atomic if you put `WITH RR` on the `SELECT`.